# Basic "ng serve" app fails to run after creating "ng new FirstApp"

Tags: node.js, angular

**main.ts** - `Error: Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module-@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\babel\webpack-loader.js`

**app.component.scss** - `Error: Module build failed- node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js`

`Module not found:` `Error: Can't resolve index.js?protocol=auto%3A&username=&password=&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=0&pathname=%2Fws&logging=info&reconnect=10'`

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

× Failed to compile.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8T8HO.jpg

package.json

```
{
  "name": "first-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.4.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: What are the steps you followed to create the app?

Comment: ALso paste you package.json file

Comment: @Sohan i am very new to angular so basically ran  1.ng new FirstApp 2.cd FirstApp 3.ng serve

Comment: Did you check your node_modules? Are those in path of your proejct.I cannot see issue running on my local

Comment: Yes the files are present on the location .I don't understand what is causing the problem on my system when the files are present. Tried rm -rf node_modules  and again npm install ,didn't work.

Comment: I started from scratch, did not run any npm install , try cleaning everything in dir and run these as you did earlier
`ng new FirstApp`
`cd FirstApp`
`ng serve `

Comment: Try npm update. Seems to be a common solution to the error Module build failed

Comment: @Sohan Created the new project on different drive (E)  from scratch ,it worked .Thanks

Comment: ok, i will try and add this as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like environmental issue.
I did tried on my local  machine from scratch and this works with no issues.
try cleaning your local directory completely and run following:

```
ng new FirstApp 
cd FirstApp 
ng serve
```